# Analyze code in dataframe with Tidycode in R

Tags: r

I am trying to take R code, stored in cells of the content column of a dataframe, and analyze the functions used by applying the Tidycode package. However, I first need to convert the data to a Matahari tibble before applying an unnest_calls() function.

Here is the data:

```
data <- read.csv("https://github.com/making-data-science-count/TidyTuesday-Analysis/raw/master/db-tmp/cleaned%20database.csv")
```

I have tried doing this in a number of different ways, including extracting each row (in the content column ) as an Rfile and then reading it back in with Tidycode calls, for example:

```
tmp<-data$content2[1])
writeLines(tmp, "tmp.R") #I've also used save() and write()

rfile<-tidycode::read_rfiles("tmp.R")
```

But, I keep getting errors such as: `"Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:14: unexpected symbol
1: library(here)library"`

Ultimately, what I would like to do is analyze the different types of code per file, and keep that linked with the other data in the `data` dataframe, such as date and username.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!